# How do I call an executable from a C program (using winapi)?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

[CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) came up a few times searching google....
Is it OK to assume this is the safest and most efficient method?
If so, I would like to use the output of the called process.
How do I know it has completed before continuing on in the C program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) Can be used to create a process, its a more convenient way to pass arguments.

But if you want to use the output of the process then `CreateProcess` is probably your best bet

With `CreateProcess` you can pass a [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(VS.85).aspx) structure that can be used to pass a file pipe handle to Standard Out of the process.

`CreateProcess` will return a [PROCESS_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873(VS.85).aspx) structure containing a HANDLE to the created process. That handle will become signalled when the process exits.

So You can [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx) on the process handle to wait for the output to be complete.

Don't forget to `CloseHandle` on the process handle and thread handle when you are done.

Comment: If the process you want to start requires elevation (or Vista/7 automatically thinks it does, because of its filename or another heuristic) CreateProcess will fail and you'll need to handle that specific error.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756945.aspx.  ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx are easiest, and the second lets you get process information that I think includes a process handle you can use as John describes.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you measure efficiency.  [`system()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28VS.80%29.aspx) is programmer efficient.

Also see [`exec()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0k9bb%28VS.80%29.aspx) and its many brothers.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProcess()` is a fairly low-level function for spawning subprocesses and may not be the most convenient option. For a C program where you need to read the output, consider [`popen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.71).aspx) (note that the MS CRT places an underscore before its name):

```
FILE *f = _popen("dir", "r");
char buf[1000];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
    // .. process output using stdio functions
}
_pclose(f);
```

Comment: popen() will not work from a GUI ap, only from a console. And please don't suggest while (!feof(f)) { - it's misused enough as it is.

Comment: From MSDN "If used in a Windows program, the _popen function returns an invalid file pointer that will cause the program to hang indefinitely. _popen  works properly in a Console application." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The classic source for how to execute  a Windows program and catch its output is [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) - it's actually not as complicated as it looks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need full control (change std in/out etc), CreateProcess is your best option. If you are executing something specified by the user, you really need to use ShellExecute[Ex] since CreateProcess will fail for applications that require UAC elevation (ShellExecuteEx is also able to give you a handle to the child process when you start **applications**)